# Access a constant from the companion class inside a method defined in a trait

Tags: scala, oop, traits

I have created a trait called Animal and two classes, Dog and Cat. Both Dog and Cat have companion classes that store the number of lives they have. My Cat object has 9 lives and my Dog object has 1 life. I want to add a function to the Animal trait called isAlive and implement there. The isAlive function needs access to the number of live the Animal has. How would I get access to the lives value in the companion classes?

Should I just move the lives value into the Class and remove the companion classes?

Here's my code.

**The trait**

```
package Animal

trait Animal {

  def speak: String

  def getDeaths: Int

  def isAlive: Boolean = {
    getDeaths < 1 // I want to replace 1 with the number of lives from the Dog or Cat
  }
}
```

**The Cat Class and Companion Class**

```
package Animal

class Cat(a: Int) extends Animal {
  private var age: Int = a
  private var deaths: Int = 0

  def this() = this(0)

  override def speak: String = {
    if (this.isAlive) {
      "Meow"
    }
    else {
      "..."
    }
  }

  // I want to do this in the trait
  // override def isAlive: Boolean = this.deaths <= Cat.lives

  def setAge(age: Int): Unit = this.age = age

  def getAge: Int = this.age

  def getDeaths: Int = this.deaths

  def die(): Unit = this.deaths += 1

}

object Cat {
  val lives: Int = 9
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd include `lives` as an abstract method in `Animal` trait, similar to `getDeaths` (btw, Scala doesn't follow Java's [naming conventions for getters and setters](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#accessorsmutators)).

If you're familiar with Java, companion object in scala is similar to Java's `static`, meaning that type resolution of `objects` happens in compile time and it's not possible to use polymorphism the same way as you do with methods and fields of the `class`.

Here is the code:

```
trait Animal {
  def speak: String
  def getDeaths: Int
  def lives: Int

  def isAlive: Boolean = {
    getDeaths < lives
  }
}


class Cat(a: Int) extends Animal {
  override val lives: Int = 9

  private var age: Int = a
  private var deaths: Int = 0

  def this() = this(0)

   /* ... */
}
```

Alternatively, you can defined `lives` constant in companion object and reference it in concrete class when overriding `lives` method:

```
class Cat(a: Int) extends Animal {
  override val lives: Int = Cat.lives

  private var age: Int = a
  private var deaths: Int = 0

  def this() = this(0)

   /* ... */
}

object Cat {
  val lives = 9
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To access `lives` within a `trait` it either has to be a part of the trait, as @Alvean has pointed out, or you have to make it a requirement that classes extending the trait need to have it.

```
trait Animal { self: {val lives: Int} =>
  def isAlive: Boolean = getDeaths < lives
  . . .
}

class Cat(a: Int) extends Animal {
  val lives = Cat.lives  //required to be an Animal
  . . .
}
```

Comment: Note, that this declaration `self: {val lives: Int} => ` makes `lives` a method that is invoked through reflection call. It may lead to suboptimal performance in real world applications.